# Spring creates twice a child bean on inheritance and never creates parent bean

Tags: spring, inheritance, dependency-injection

I have such configuration:

```
  @Configuration
  public class A {

    @Bean("A")
    public WebServiceTemplate webServiceTemplate() throws Exception {
        return createTemplate();
    }

    WebServiceTemplate createTemplate() throws Exception {
        WebServiceTemplate webServiceTemplate = new WebServiceTemplate();
    webServiceTemplate.setDefaultUri(url_01); 
       ..........
       .........
        return webServiceTemplate;
    }
  }


  @Configuration
  public class B extends A {

    @Bean("B")
    public WebServiceTemplate anotherWebServiceTemplate() throws Exception {
      WebServiceTemplate template = createTemplate();
      template.setDefaultUri(url_02);
      return template;
    }
  }
```

The problem is that Spring autowires @Bean("B") twice: when I autowire it with @Qualifier("A") and  when I autowire it with @Qualifier("B"):

```
  @Qualifier("A")
  private @Autowired WebServiceTemplate template; (here is template with url_02)
    
  @Qualifier("B")
  private @Autowired WebServiceTemplate template; (here is template with url_02)
```

In debug mode I see that Spring creates `@Bean("B")` twice and never creates `@Bean("A")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`anotherWebServiceTemplate` uses the same object generated by `createTemplate`, that the reason why you really have the same content in both ones (really you have only one object).

You should create again a new instance with the desired configuration for the second one. Spring by default uses Singleton for their beans so you will have only 2 instances of `WebServiceTemplate`.

Not sure why you need inheritance to work with templates, but in any case, you can adapt the following "example code" in an easy way:

```
@Configuration
public class TemplatesConfiguration {

  @Bean
  @Primary
  @Qualifier("defaultTemplate")
  public WebServiceTemplate createTemplate() {
    WebServiceTemplate webServiceTemplate = new WebServiceTemplate();
    webServiceTemplate.setDefaultUri("url_01");
    ...
    return webServiceTemplate;
  }

  @Bean
  @Qualifier("anotherTemplate")
  public WebServiceTemplate anotherWebServiceTemplate() {
    // Create a new object instead use the one generated in createTemplate method
    WebServiceTemplate webServiceTemplate = new WebServiceTemplate();
    webServiceTemplate.setDefaultUri("url_02");
    ...
    return webServiceTemplate;
  }

}
```

Example of a class that uses both:

```
@Service
public class TemplatesService {

  @Autowired
  @Qualifier("defaultTemplate")
  private final WebServiceTemplate template1;

  @Autowired
  @Qualifier("anotherTemplate")
  private final WebServiceTemplate template2;

  ...
}
```

In this case, `template1` and `template2` will contain the "desired string" (and any other specific configuration).

Comment: Thank U for answer.
I need inheritance to work with templates because createTemplate() use some other methods with enough much code to initiate template, so I want to avoid code duplication, because in the anotherWebServiceTemplate() I change just two parameters

Comment: I need to change dynamically this templates in asynchronous requests, so do I understand correctly that in this case I can’t use Singletone beans and must use Prototype?

Comment: The answer depends of your business logic. With `Prototype` you will get a new instance every time, here you can see an explanation of every one: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-bean-scopes. If you have to be sure no property is "overwrite" for any other request, but no problem sharing the same instance (with same properties) in the current one (in differents parts of the code), maybe `Request` scope could be an option. If every time you get that bean, you want to be sure no other class will share the same object, then `Prototype` could be more suitable.

Comment: In any case, be sure you are not reusing the same object, that is what is happening with your current implementation.